# .htaccess mask/cloak image source URLs

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I hope you can help me.

I have the problem that I would like to mask URLs from another (not on my server) Domain

```
<img src="https://images2.externaldomain.com/?w=200&amp;h=200&amp;bg=white&amp;trim=5&amp;t=letterbox&amp;url=ssl%3Ai.otto.de%2Fi%2Fotto%2F60393181-9d98-5221-b0ab-35d38cd2aee2.jpg%3F%24Preset_Retargeting_640%24&amp;feedId=62797&amp;k=bd10410eeddf3ad8980f6e543edf4455110cb164">
```

to a masked URL like

```
<img src="https://mysubdomain.mydomain.com/productimages/bd10410eeddf3ad8980f6e543edf4455110cb164.jpg">
```

The image ID should the ID at the end `k=`

The problem is that I need a wildcard solution because I have a lot images with these URLs and only `https://images2.externaldomain.com` is stable. Every image has an ID (k=) in the source URL.

which `RewriteRule` or Condition could work?

many thank to every hint!

I added the snippet into my .htaccess without effect on my html. the sources of the images look exactly the same. how can I mask them that it look like image source of my server?

the hint of MrWhite was great and it works on https://htaccess.madewithlove.com/ but not on my site - what did I wrong?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)k=([\da-f]+)
 RewriteRule ^$ productimages/%1.jpg [QSD,L]
</IfModule>
```

My images are look like:

```
<img src="https://images2.externaldomain.com/?w=200&amp;h=200&amp;bg=white&amp;trim=5&amp;t=letterbox&amp;url=ssl%3Ai.otto.de%2Fi%2Fotto%2F60393181-9d98-5221-b0ab-35d38cd2aee2.jpg%3F%24Preset_Retargeting_640%24&amp;feedId=62797&amp;k=bd10410eeddf3ad8980f6e543edf4455110cb164">
```

or

```
<img src="https://images2.externaldomain.com/?w=200&amp;h=200&amp;bg=white&amp;trim=5&amp;t=letterbox&amp;url=ssl%3Ai.otto.de%2Fi%2Fotto%2F06a05fc1-0554-5463-a8cf-6092a79214f0.jpg%3F%24Preset_Retargeting_640%24&amp;feedId=56149&amp;k=d27dd6627f26f5350af6afcec2c2afd71500c218">
```

in HTML code. Images are external on another server.

I would like to mask or cloak them with htts://mysubdomain.mydomain.com/productimages/d27dd6627f26f5350af6afcec2c2afd71500c218.jpg

Comment: You need to capture the image name out of the query string using a RewriteCond, `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} test%2F(.*\.jpg)` should probably do. And then use the back reference to that match in your RewriteRule, `RewriteRule ^$ https://mysubdomain.mydomain.com/folder/%1?`

Comment: thank you - is it also possible to take the last ID (after k=) as image ID?

Comment: Pattern `k=(.*)`, and you will have to append the `.jpg` to the substitution URL yourself then. If there could be anything _after_ the `k=...` part, an additional parameter, then you would need to exclude that as well, probably easiest using a pattern with a negative character class that allows everything _but_ `&`.

Comment: Do you not need any of the other URL parameters? Don't you have the "rewrite" in the wrong direction? Or do you mean "redirect"?

Comment: in would like to mask some image links from an external site as it looks like image links from my site

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work.

Comment: Are `subdomain.domain.example` and `mysubdomain.mydomain.example` really the same hostname (as I assumed in my answer below) or are these in fact different hosts? If they are different, how do they relate to each other, where do they resolve, etc.?

Comment: Hello MrWhite both domains are different

Comment: I tried to mask the image links wich are in my website like <img src="subdomain.theotherdomain.com/?w=200&h=200&bg=white&trim=5&t=letterbox&url=ssl%3Ai.test.com%2Fi%test%2F37b3895d-f743-4572-9017-6725903fef30.jpg%3F%24Preset_Retargeting_640%24&feedId=62797&k=4c8370f2e926de654b1f0a08530bc6065e6a80d3" />

I would like to have implemented images like

<img src="mysubdomain.mydomain.com/4c8370f2e926de654b1f0a08530bc6065e6a80d3.jpg" /> that shows the same image and looks for the crawlers like an internal image

Comment: And how do these domains relate to each other? Are they both under your control? Do they resolve to the same server or different servers? Is `subdomain.theotherdomain.com` a third party domain and not under your control? However, an immediate (potential) "problem" with this scenario is all the other URL params (as I asked above). Can these other URL params simply be ignored? Or can they be hardcoded?

Comment: What you are asking now in comments is completely different to what you are asking in your question and in the "opposite directive" - a concern which I also raised in my comment above, but you have seemingly chosen to ignore?

Comment: The other domain is not under my control.
All other parameters can be ignored. I only would like to use the "k" Parameter

Comment: I hope I use the technical terms right. If not, I will correct it - sorry for that. I think my comment explains what I want to do

Comment: @Hendrik How did you get on with my answer?

Comment: @MrWhite I pasted your suggestion in my .htaccess but without any effect. I have no idea how this masking could work.

Answer (score 1):

To internally rewrite a URL of the form:

`/?w=200&h=200&bg=white&trim=5&t=letterbox&url=ssl%3Ai.test.com%2Fi%test%2F37b3895d-f743-4572-9017-6725903fef30.jpg%3F%24Preset_Retargeting_640%24&feedId=62797&k=4c8370f2e926de654b1f0a08530bc6065e6a80d3`

to

`/folder/4c8370f2e926de654b1f0a08530bc6065e6a80d3.jpg`

In other words, capturing the value of the `k` URL parameter in the originally requested URL and use this as the file basename in the URL being rewritten to, then you can do something like the following using mod_rewrite near the top of the root `.htaccess` file (the order of directives can be important):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)k=([\da-f]+)
RewriteRule ^$ folder/%1.jpg [QSD,L]
```

This ignores all other URL parameters and looks only for the `k` URL param. This param can occur anywhere in the query string.

`([\da-f]+)` - This regex matches the value of the `k` URL param, which looks like a hexadecimal string. In your example this is 40 characters long - if it is always 40 characters long then this could be limited in the regex as well. eg `([\da-f]{40})` - to only match hex strings that are 40 characters long.

Optionally, you can also test whether the target URL exists as a file *before* rewriting the request. For example, add the following *condition* (`RewriteCond` directive) after the first:

```
:
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/folder/%1.jpg -f
:
```

Comment: I added 
`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)k=([\da-f]+)
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/folder/%1.jpg -f
RewriteRule ^$ folder/%1.jpg [QSD,L]
</IfModule>`
but without effect.

an image like <img src="https://images2.productserve.com/?w=200&amp;h=200&amp;bg=white&amp;trim=5&amp;t=letterbox&amp;url=ssl%3Ai.otto.de%2Fi%2Fotto%2Fed7348e8-ae3e-5072-8757-24622eb12b87.jpg%3F%24Preset_Retargeting_640%24&amp;feedId=56149&amp;k=1f491ef168980ecc32364fe726c03b1429c22996"> 
will not be mask in kind of /folder/1f491ef168980ecc32364fe726c03b1429c22996.jpg